# In Python, check for zeros in each row, if row has 3 or more zeros, remove the row. Current code does nothing to the file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, zero

I'm looking to count the amount of zeros in a row. If it has three or more zeros, remove the row. Once all rows with three or more zeros are removed, export the new file.

CSV:

| Year | 2010 | 2011 | 2012 | 2013 | 2014 | 2015 | 2016 | 2017 | 2018 | 2019 | 2020 | 2021 | 2022 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Person_A | $10.00 | $20.00 | $20.00 | $50.00 | $0.00 | $10.00 | $0.00 | $0.00 | $50.00 | $0.00 | $10.00 | $0.00 | $1.00 |
| Person_B | $100.00 | $150.00 | $1.00 | $50.00 | $0.25 | $100.00 | $0.00 | $50.00 | $60.00 | $50.00 | $0.00 | $0.00 | $1000.00 |

Desired result:

| Year | 2010 | 2011 | 2012 | 2013 | 2014 | 2015 | 2016 | 2017 | 2018 | 2019 | 2020 | 2021 | 2022 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Person_B | $100.00 | $150.00 | $1.00 | $50.00 | $0.25 | $100.00 | $0.00 | $50.00 | $60.00 | $50.00 | $0.00 | $0.00 | $1000.00 |

Current Code does nothing to the file. I have what I think is count zeros, if more than 3 drop the row, but the row count for File.csv and NewFile.csv are the same:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/File.CSV" , encoding = "ISO-8859-1") # import csv as DataFrame

df_new = df.loc[df.eq(0).sum(1).le(3),] # Look for zeros, if more than 3, remove row

df_new.to_csv( "C:/Users/Folder/NewFile.CSV", index=False ) # Export new file
```

I have also attempted this, but again makes no changes to File:

```
df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/File.CSV" , encoding = "ISO-8859-1") # import csv as DataFrame

df_new = df[df.eq('$0.00').sum(1) <= 3] # Look for zeros, if more than 3 remove row

df_new.to_csv( "C:/Users/Folder/NewFile.CSV", index=False ) # Export new file
```

Comment: Why do you compare to `0` if your cells contain `$0.00`?

Comment: Corralien's answer likely highlights the issue, your values probably aren't being read in as numbers, but rather as strings, which means you need to either treat them as such, or modify them for your expected results~

Comment: Thank you for the input. I attempted Corralien's answer, but it also made no changes to File. I edited my post to reflect this attempt.

Comment: What is the output of `df.filter(regex='\d{4}').stack().eq('$0.00').value_counts()`?

Comment: New file has only A1 filled in with a zero.

Comment: Is it possible for you to share your csv file?

Comment: Here you are: https://filedropper.com/d/s/y2AlkrZta8QJKl6jEgtVT6xKUpUbNx

Comment: You have many trailing whitespace. You have to clean your data

Comment: Ah, that is an error in the program exporting the data to excel. I will have to work on correcting that first then. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

```
df = pd.read_csv('GiftYearTotal.csv', encoding='ISO-8859-1')
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip())
out = df[df.eq('$0.00').sum(1) <= 3]
```

---

**Old answer**

You can use:

```
out = df[df.eq('$0.00').sum(1) <= 3]
print(out)

# Output
       Year     2010     2011   2012    2013   2014     2015   2016    2017    2018    2019   2020   2021      2022
1  Person_B  $100.00  $150.00  $1.00  $50.00  $0.25  $100.00  $0.00  $50.00  $60.00  $50.00  $0.00  $0.00  $1000.00
```

Comment: I attempted this, but it does not make any changes to files. Edited my post to show exactly how I incorporated your answer.